# Display Drawing with true scale

Tags: interface-design, autocad

I am trying to display a drawing with true physical dimensions. I want the dimensions of the drawing that's being displayed to be accurate. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Are you really using autocad? You mean modelspace paperspace? The computer does not actually know what size your monitor is so you need to look up the monittors specs or measure it.

Comment: Yea, I am using AutoCAD, I am converting the drawing to pdf from Model space with 1:1 scale. When I use the View11 add-on in AutoCAD and measure the dimensions, they are accurate. But when I view the PDF with actual size (100%) there is a slight difference in dimensions.

Comment: I am trying to display the drawing in a Web application. It doesn't have to be an AutoCAD file. Is there any way I can design/display a drawing with accurate physical dimensions?

Comment: No there is no way

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question keeps mutating to a totally different question all the time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic way for a display application to know what the size of the screen is. Especially across different computer systems. 1:1 and 100% does not even generically mean 1:1 reproduction size but rather one pixel is one pixel whatever that pixels size happens to be on your screen.

Sure you can measure the screen and compensate. Its easy to do if you can control all the hardware. But you can not make sure every device everywhere does this.

Comment: just to enhance with specifics, there must be a clear relationship between inches and pixels in order to have a 100% size in inches. A 1080p monitor (at 16:9 aspect ratio) is expected to be 1920x1080 pixels and assuming the same dot pitch on both monitors, an image with those pixel dimensions at 100% will be half the size in inches on a 10 inch wide monitor as compared to 100% on a 20 inch wide monitor. If one has complete control over the entire display chain, then it is possible. For general use it is not possible to control the entire display ecosystem of random users.

Comment: @joojaa - Even if there isn't an actual option to do this in Autocad, couldn't it still be done by physically measuring an object of known length on a screen using a ruler, so that you can determine the correct zoom level? I've done this in Illustrator (which also has no such option).

Comment: Autocad has an option. Op is just looking to share it with clients at that size @BillyKerr sure but it requires the client to do the work since the only time youd actually care of this factor is if understanding true size is important for your business. Then every client who does not do it would be really agnry at you.

Comment: @joojaa - I see that now, didn't read the comments properly. Displaying the actual physical size on every web browser on all monitors automatically is impossible.

Comment: If not for multiple monitors is it at least possible for a single screen? Basically I am trying to display a True scaled 1-metre long drawing in two video wall displays placed side by side in portrait orientation. The resolution of the display is 1920*1080 pixels

Comment: If its your hardware just measure what you got and do target size / measured size and insert that in your scale parameter @Gautham Now obviously if your screens are different sizes than your introuble. But ok not hard show two images. Anyway your not getting good ansers because your asking a x/y question

Comment: Like I mentioned earlier, the drawing is 1-metre long, I can't display it on one screen. That's the reason I am configuring two displays as one big screen.

Comment: @Gautham you can make 2 separate viewers one for each screen. But if the screens are identical then obviously jsut measuring one is enough. Printing would be easier though. Anyway this is not your original question